# I can't identify the last character in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm new to Javascript and I'm building a simple calculator. I want to identify the last character entered in the calculator display so I can block the input when the user tries to enter double symbols such (`++`, `./`, `*-`, etc.)

The input is a string, so I'm trying to use the `.slice(-1)` or the `.charAt(str.length-1)` methods, but these bring back not the last character entered, but the previous one.

For example, if I enter the number `839`, the methods bring back the `3`, not the `9`.
Any ideas of why this could be?

I have a feeling this has to do with the part of my code where I'm executing this methods, but I couldn't figure it out so far.

Here you can find the whole code: https://github.com/coccagerman/calculator
Here goes the function that prints the values in the display:

```
function printButton(e) {
    let calculatorDisplay = document.getElementById("calculatorDisplay").innerHTML
    let pressedKeyValue = e.target.getAttribute('value')
    var lastCharacter

    console.log('pressedKeyValue ' + pressedKeyValue)
    console.log('calculatorDisplay ' + calculatorDisplay)

    if (pressedKeyValue == '.' && calculatorDisplay.includes('.')) { }
    else if (
        (pressedKeyValue == '.' && calculatorDisplay == '') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '-' && calculatorDisplay == '') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '+' && calculatorDisplay == '') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '*' && calculatorDisplay == '') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '/' && calculatorDisplay == '')
    ) { }
    else if (
        (pressedKeyValue == '.' && lastCharacter == '+') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '.' && lastCharacter == '-') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '.' && lastCharacter == '/') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '.' && lastCharacter == '*') ||

        (pressedKeyValue == '+' && lastCharacter == '+') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '+' && lastCharacter == '-') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '+' && lastCharacter == '/') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '+' && lastCharacter == '*') ||

        (pressedKeyValue == '-' && lastCharacter == '+') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '-' && lastCharacter == '-') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '-' && lastCharacter == '/') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '-' && lastCharacter == '*') ||

        (pressedKeyValue == '*' && lastCharacter == '+') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '*' && lastCharacter == '-') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '*' && lastCharacter == '/') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '*' && lastCharacter == '*') ||

        (pressedKeyValue == '/' && lastCharacter == '+') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '/' && lastCharacter == '-') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '/' && lastCharacter == '/') ||
        (pressedKeyValue == '/' && lastCharacter == '*')
    ) { }
    else if (calculatorDisplay == '') {
        document.getElementById("calculatorDisplay").innerHTML = pressedKeyValue
        lastCharacter = calculatorDisplay.slice(-1)
        console.log('lastCharacter inside ' + lastCharacter)
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("calculatorDisplay").innerHTML += pressedKeyValue
        lastCharacter = calculatorDisplay.slice(-1)
        console.log('lastCharacter inside ' + lastCharacter)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `pop` instead, see if it works, more infos [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the `calculatorDisplay` variable at the very beginning of the method, and you're not updating it once you update the element that it's based on.

```
calculatorDisplay += pressedKeyValue
document.getElementById("calculatorDisplay").innerHTML = calculatorDisplay 
lastCharacter = calculatorDisplay.slice(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to get the last character of a string.

```js
const string = "+-";

// Method 1
const lastCharacter1 = string.slice(string.length - 1);
console.log(lastCharacter1);

// Method 2
const lastCharacter2 = string.slice(-1);
console.log(lastCharacter2);

// Method 3
const lastCharacter3 = string.split("").pop();
console.log(lastCharacter3);

// Method 4
const lastCharacter4 = string.charAt(string.length - 1);
console.log(lastCharacter4);
```